# My torrents are paused on Rtorrent/Rutorrent, how to fix this?

Tags: server, docker, rtorrent, rutorrent

So I've build a docker script for rtorrent/rutorrent, this one in particular: https://hub.docker.com/r/diameter/rtorrent-rutorrent

From the start we had some issues regarding the plugins directory (I had to rename it and then rename back to the original name) and regarding the autodl2.cfg file deprecated.

Now, for some reason my torrents ain't starting, I've tried to correct the write and read permissions of the download and watch directory, and it didn't work, later I tried to give full permission, also nothing, I've corrected the paths of watch and torrents files on all .rtorrent.rc in order to fix it, yet it didn't work either.

What can I do in this case? I'm using ubuntu 18.04.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So I've found out the problem, this specific dir didn't have the correct permissions, so I had to correct them like this.

chmod -R go+rX /var/lib/docker/overlay2/b01d07fa263968c359c9abe9a6238ce46bd038d3b6f2963dc7adda032f495208/merged/home/rtorrent